# Alternative xquery with no use of Group by

Tags: xquery

The following XML sample shows data records of type 'Master', which are linked to 0..N contents of type 'Series'. I want to detect the number of existing Series records for Masters with the same title () attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<program_file fechaCreacion="20180919184224">
    <version>1.0</version>
    <programs>
        <program id_programa="1">
          <tipo_programa>Master</tipo_programa>
          <titulo >tit1</titulo>
          <año>2018</año>
        </program>
        <program id_programa="2">
          <tipo_programa>Master</tipo_programa>
          <titulo >tit1</titulo>
          <año>2018</año>
        </program>
           <program id_programa="3">
          <tipo_programa>Master</tipo_programa>
          <titulo >tit2</titulo>
          <año>2018</año>
        </program>
        <program id_programa="5">
          <id_serie>1</id_serie>
          <tipo_programa>Series</tipo_programa>
          <episodio>8</episodio>
          <temporada>1</temporada>
          <titulo >tit1</titulo>
          <año>2018</año>
        </program>
        <program id_programa="6">
          <id_serie>2</id_serie>
          <tipo_programa>Series</tipo_programa>
          <episodio>8</episodio>
          <temporada>1</temporada>
          <titulo >tit1</titulo>
          <año>2018</año>
        </program>
        <program id_programa="7">
          <id_serie>3</id_serie>
          <tipo_programa>Series</tipo_programa>
          <episodio>8</episodio>
          <temporada>1</temporada>
          <titulo >tit2</titulo>
          <año>2018</año>
        </program>      
    </programs>
</program_file>
```

With this example what I expect to obtain, in a tabular format, is:
[image]

I managed to make a query that gives me the correct results (with BaseX) using Group by:

```
let $dup_masters := doc("C:/Users/fgarcia/Documents/Optiva/Orange/programs_sample.xml")/program_file/programs
    return
    <distinct-names> {
      for $dups in $dup_masters/program 
        order by $dups/titulo
        group by $title := $dups/titulo
        return
          if(count(distinct-values($dups[tipo_programa="Master"]/@id_programa)) > 1) then
            element {"Master"}
                    { 
                      attribute {"title"} {$title},
                      for $id in distinct-values($dups[tipo_programa="Master"]/@id_programa) 
                      return ( 
                        <td>{$id}</td>, 
                        <td>{count($dups[id_serie=($id)])}</td>
                      )      
                    }
          else ()  
      }</distinct-names>
```

The problem is that when I move this code to Exist-db I obtain no results, and I'm wondering if this can be related to the implementation of Group By in exist. Any ideas/hints on how to solve this in a different manner are welcome!

Comment: I think you would better state exactly which version of eXist-db you use and add a tag for that database to your question, then also provide a minimal but complete sample of input/XQuery/output, the query yo have shown returns some XML, explain what relation that XML has to the tabular data in your image.

Comment: Your query works fine for me in [eXide](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/eXide/index.html), with the same result as BaseX. Have you verifies that you can actually [open the XML data](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/uploading-files)?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In fact you were right Leo..... I did not change the path to the XML data correctly and so the error. I still have something to solve regarding formatting of the output as a table but this is mainly HTML stuff (something I'm also new.... but should be able to manage it myself)